# how to get info about a paypal transaction using paypal api

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to get transaction details using PayPal transaction ID with Paypal API, but all I get is "Requested resource ID was not found.", I don't know if I do anything wrong or if there is a problem with PayPal's API. Can someone help me?

all I want to do is to check with a transaction id if this transaction was finished. I tried doing it with PayPal API - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/

I think my problem is with the 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-CONTEXT' parameter.

I tried filling 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-CONTEXT' like the given example in the docs but it doesn't work:

and then I tried this (still doesnt work):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer [My Token]',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = (
    ('transaction_id', '81795386U4841702W'),
    ('fields', 'all'),
    ('page_size', '100'),
    ('page', '1'),
)

    response = requests.get('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions', headers=headers, params=params)
    print(response)
```

Comment: If you visit paypal developers page there are a lot of apis that can call for different kind of data, there are also events that you can trigger and call apis on your server in response to those events

Comment: What is `81795386U4841702W` ? Where is it from? Apparently it is not a transaction ID in sandbox mode, hence Resource ID not found is expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide information about your existing PayPal integration (there are many) nor the call that said Resource ID not found, so here is the best way to proceed in general:

Use [a standard PayPal integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), and when the `capture` route calls that PayPal API to finalize a transaction, the PayPal transaction ID will be in `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id` (separate from the Order ID, which is not useful for accounting purposes).  Alongside this capture ID you will find all the information you need about the PayPal transaction.

It should not be necessary (nor is it recommended) to call any other API, but there is a v2/payments capture detail endpoint as well as a separate Transaction Search API. (Again neither of those APIs should be necessary nor is their use generally advisable)

Comment: ok, I see that I didn't explain myself well at all, I edited my question